# Prohibit http:// YouTube URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a text field where a user can input any YouTube links. The regex that I am using allows URL with even `http://`.

Somehow I wanted to restrict the use of `http://` in the URL. I tried many posts in the community. But still I am not getting any solution to prohibit the use of `http://`.

My regex:

```js
(?:https?:\/\/)?((www\.)?youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$
```

Comment: Use `<input type="url" ...`

Comment: I want to prohibit use from entering http:// in the url

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I have edited the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `?` after the `s` which makes the `s` optional and add an anchor at the beginning:

```
^(?:https:\/\/)?((www\.)?youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$
#       ^^^
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/BhCyjH/1).

Comment: Thanks, While editing i also came up with this. ^https:\/\/+?((www\.)?youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$

Comment: @tkamath99: This requires `https://` in every url. Thus `www.youtube.com` would be invalid then.

Comment: i tried in regexer.com. Your solution It still accepts http://

Comment: @tkamath99: True, added an anchor, now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

RegEX is always slower and heavy in execution. Simpler solution could be to use startWith function of javascript (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp).

if(txt.val().startWith("https://www.youtube.com") || txt.val().startWith("https://www.youtu.be")){
//do your stuff
}